# javaScript Promise

Tags: javascript

Необходимо сделать костыль для сайта. Сайт задумывался с использованием WebSocket но на продакшене он почему-то запрещен (wss запрещен). Встала задача переделать все без использования wss. Необходимо отправлять на браузер сообщения по команде сервера. Еще раньше использовался  XMLHttpRequest, но он не подходит, т.к. у браузеров есть ограничения по количеству XMLHttpRequest соединений (5-8).

Серверная часть проекта на JSF + primefases.

НЕобходимо, что бы команды от сервера поступали на веб достаточно быстро + может быть много пользователей, поэтому регулярные запросы на сервер (раз в секунду) не сильно подходят.

Хочу создать асинхрнные запросы js. Обычные запросы на сервер отрабатывают, и можно не отправлять ответ обратно на браузер до тех пор пока сервер не захочет отправить команду. Когда сервер отправит ответ, js его получит, выполнит что надо и сразу отправит еще один такой же запрос. Цикл повторится. НО! если js ожидает команду, то весь остальной js "висит" и ждет ответ. Вроде как можно сделать асинхронные запросы, такие что после отправки запроса на сервер, остальной JS продолжит работу, но у меня почему то не получается.

Я использую Promise. Сделал тестовую программку. По замыслу: вызывается обновление таймеров раз в секунду. Один таймер с ожиданием в 4 секунды. Я хотел что б один таймер обновлялся раз в сек. а второй раз в 4 (ну или так же раз в секунду но с задержнкой, с неком смещением фазы).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var el;
var el2;
var i=0;
var i2=0;
onload = function(){
setInterval(function(){
    update();
    update2();
    },1000);
}

var update = function(){
newPromise().then(
function(){
            el = document.getElementById("test");
            i=Number(i)+Number(1);
            el.innerText = i;}
            );
};

function newPromise(){ 
return new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        if (true) {
            sleep(4000);
            resolve(true); 
        } else {
            var reason = new Error('error');
            reject(reason); 
        }
    }
);
}

function update2(){
    el2 = document.getElementById("test2");
    i2=Number(i2)+Number(1);
    el2.innerText = i2;
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="test">1</h1>
<h1 id="test2">1</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Но не получается. Код ждет эти 4 сек. и не идет дальше как я ожидал.  Так ли вообще работает Promise и если не так, что можно использоать?

Comment: у вас sleep забивает весь поток, тут либо async/await либо `setTimeout(resolve, 4000, true);`

Comment: Что такое асинхронные запросы, если ajax(xmlhttprequest) не подходит?

Comment: Да, возможно я вообще не на то смотрю.  Promise это что то вообще другое. async/await посмотрю сейчас.

Comment: под запросами на сервер я понимаю обычные GET POST запросы из JS, но только хочу что бы ответ они не ждали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
let g_i = 1;
const field = document.querySelector('h1');
function updateLoop() {
  getDelayedServerData(g_i)
    .then(res => {
    field.innerText = res.args.data;
    g_i++;
    setTimeout(updateLoop)
  });
}
updateLoop();


function getDelayedServerData(i) {
  return fetch('https://httpbin.org/delay/2?data='+i).then(res => res.json());
}

{ // Другой js в это время прекрасно работает 
  const sec = document.getElementById('second');
  let i = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    second.innerText = ++i;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<h1>0</h1>
<span id="second"></span>
```

setInterval неизбежно породит проблемы при проскальзывании. Отправлять следующий запрос нужно, когда получен ответ на предыдущий, а не по таймеру.

Comment: а return fetch('https://httpbin.org/delay/2?data='+i).then(res => res.json()); Это что?

Comment: [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) - это аякс запрос, возвращающий Promise, Нативная функция браузера.

Comment: httpbin.org - просто публичный сервис, для подобного роста тестов)

Comment: Прикольный сайт. А можно сделать как то так, что бы при длительном ответе от сервера fetch('https://httpbin.org/delay/200?data='+i) код не ждал выполнения запроса.

Comment: Так он и не ждёт, кладёт обработчик в eventLoop, как придёт ответ обработчик выполнится.